# Best way to return different API response based on user role (Prisma/NestJS)

Tags: api, nestjs, prisma

I’m developing a REST API using NestJS and Prisma. The RBAC is done using an enum with a role guard.

I would like to use the same controller method for different user roles and return specific fields only for specific roles.

What’s the best way to do this?

Like ADMIN role should return all fields while USER role should only return certain fields.

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible in your case, you can describe your select opition in prisma request based on RBAC

```js
const getUser: object | null = await prisma.user.findUnique({
  where: {
    id: 22,
  },
  select: {
    email: role === Role.Admin, // <== like this
    name: [Role.Admin, Role.User].includes(role), // <== or like this with multiple roles
  },
})
```

Comment: Is it also possible to create a DTO for the response with group decorators and then converting the Prisma data object to the DTO before returning the response to the user?